# in mysql, how can a user create owner database and write in?

Tags: mysql, sql, privileges

i all

i was able to assign privilege to create new database to a user with

```
root> GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
newuser> create database newdb;
newuser> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

now, i would that the newdb just created by 'newuser' was writable by newuser itself.

```
newuser> CREATE TABLE newtable ( id INT );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
newuser> INSERT INTO newtable (id) VALUES (1);
ERROR 1142 (42000): INSERT command denied to user 'offique'@'localhost' for table 'newtable'
```

i try to set privileges (with same user...) without solution :-(

```
newuser> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdb.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' to database 'newdb'
```

any idea?

many thanks!

Comment: Did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after using the `GRANT` command?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html

Comment: thanks dak
but it would be unhelpful... GRANT command cames out not well... (ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied)

Comment: With `GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';` you give the CREATE privilege to `newuser` when he connects from localhost. Have you tried granting him all the privileges?

Comment: You need to be root when adding privileges to newuser - because newuser only has the `CREATE` right.
So, 
`root> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdb.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
should have given the newuser all privileges on newdb

Comment: then... is impossible to a new user create database himself and write in without passing for root user (that giving privileges)?

Answer (score 1):

*now, i would that the newdb just created by 'newuser' was writable by newuser itself.*

In this case it is enought to give an INSERT privilege on database level -

```
GRANT INSERT ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

You should grant it from the 'root' account, because your new user has no rights to do it itself.

---

```
GRANT INSERT ON newdb.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Comment: thanks Devart.
But in this case newuser have access to all databases. I would that newuser have access only to database create itself.

Comment: @Roberto Oh, sorry. I missed it. I changed the answer.